# Ports require for user import from external AD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, adfs

I configured SharePoint portal with ADFS but unable to import users from external AD to SharePoint. So possible cause of the issue seems to be ports.

Please help me with the required ports should be open at external AD to our SharePoint server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[here is list of SP ports.](https://blogit.create.pt/fabiocarvalho/2017/02/14/sharepoint-2016-tcpip-ports/)

You need these:

```
TCP         636     User Profile Synchronization Service/Active Directory Import    Synchronizing profiles between SharePoint 2016 and AD using SLDAP (Secure LDAP)
TCP         5725    User Profile Synchronization Service    Synchronizing profiles between SharePoint 2016 and Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS)
TCP + UDP   389     User Profile Synchronization Service    LDAP Service
TCP + UDP   88      User Profile Synchronization Service    Kerberos
TCP + UDP   53      User Profile Synchronization Service    DNS
UDP         464     User Profile Service    Kerberos change password
```

Comment: So port number 636 and 5725 are SharePoint 2016 specific?

Comment: Here is SP2013 is almost the same: https://blog.blksthl.com/2013/02/21/tcpip-ports-of-sharepoint-2013/ you didnt wrote which SP version you have :) . Make it as answer thanks :)